# How to use Exim/Sendmail to stop sending email and log it that arrived via a certain SMTP server?

Tags: centos, email, exim

I have multiple accounts on this cpanel box. if someone sends an email to one of the specific cpanel accounts, e.g. smtp.some-cpanel-account.com, then it must rather be blocked and logged to file.

Is there a way to do this? I need this logic for exim:

```
if ( Arriving SMTP = smtp.my-domain.com) {
    1. log the email to a file (/home/emailer/out/)
    2. do NOT send the email
}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want simply to reject such messages then the easiest way is the ACL-filtering.

Add the next lines to the RCPT ACL of the `exim` config:

```
deny condition = ${lookup{$local_part@$domain}nwildlsearch{/path/block.list}{yes}}
   log_message = Rejected from $sender_address to $local_part@$domain
       message = Get lost, you $really_bad_words!
```

/path/block.list should be filled with:

```
^.*smtp\.some\-cpanel\-account\.com
^.*smtp\.other\-cpanel\-account\.com
. . . . .
```